# Is it possible to handle client socket event closing in Gin server (based on net/http package)?

Tags: go

https://github.com/gin-gonic/gin HTTP server is used. Is it possible to handle client socket closing? In the handler

```
 router.GET("/v1/get/*uri", func (c *gin.Context) {
     var url = c.Param("uri")
     if url[0:1] == "/" {
        url = url[1:]
     }
     req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
```

I make HTTP client request to url. If I close connection to gin server from my wget/curl client, gin HTTP client request is still processed. I would like to interrupt handler execution on client socket disconnect event to not waste resources.

Comment: Thats what request context are there for.

Comment: Replace call to http.NewRequest with [http.NewRequestWithContext](https://godoc.org/net/http#NewRequestWithContext).  Get the context from `c.Request.Context()`.   See [Request.Context](https://godoc.org/net/http#Request.Context) for documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gin.Context.Done() returns if client disconnects. http.Transport.CancelRequest() interrupts http request to an url. So http request  is made in goroutine and we wait for the first event in select:

1. http request is completed
2. client is disconnected from the gin server

   router.GET("/v1/get/*uri", func (c *gin.Context) {
   var url = c.Param("uri")
   if url[0:1] == "/" {
   url = url[1:]
   }

   ```
       tr := &http.Transport{ TLSClientConfig : (&tls.Config{ InsecureSkipVerify: true}),
                              DisableKeepAlives : false,
                              DisableCompression : false,
                              MaxIdleConns : 0,
                              MaxConnsPerHost : 0,
                              IdleConnTimeout : 0,
                              ResponseHeaderTimeout : 0,
                              ExpectContinueTimeout : 0,
                              ForceAttemptHTTP2 : true}
       client := http.Client{ Timeout: 20 * time.Second, Transport : tr}
       req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
       if err != nil {
           fail(1, "NewRequest")
       }
       for k, v := range c.Request.Header {
           req.Header.Set(k, strings.Join(v, "\n"))
       }
       is_url_done := make(chan HTTPRequestResult, 1)
       go func() {
           resp, err := client.Do(req)
           is_url_done <- HTTPRequestResult{res, err}
       }()
       for {
       select {
       case <-c.Done():
           tr.CancelRequest(req)
           return
       case r:= <-is_url_done:
           if r.err != nil {
               c.String(http.StatusInternalServerError, "Error: %v\n", r.err)
           } else {
               var headers = map[string]string{}
               for key, values := range(r.res.Header) {
                   headers[key] = strings.Join(values, ", ")
               }
               c.DataFromReader(r.res.StatusCode, r.res.ContentLength, "test", r.res.Body, headers)
           }

           return
       }
   }
   ```